# How to install pandas in Termux?

Tags: python, pandas, termux

I am trying to install pandas in Termux and it showing:

> File "setup.py", line 18, in 
> import numpy
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

But it's already installed.

See the error here:
https://pastebin.com/KdunjhRp

My android details :

```
kernal         -->  Linux                  
architecture   -->  aarch64
```

Python details :

```
Python Version   --> 3.9.7          
Clang version    --> 9.0.8           
Numpy version    -->  1.21.2
```

Comment: The off-site paste (please don't do that) suggests that you look in a temporary file. It's probably gone now, but you can regenerate it by trying again.

Comment: I don't use termux, but I wonder if [this information](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Python#Numpy_and_Scipy) would be helpful.

Comment: @r-beginners I tried everything from that website but still not solved the error..

Answer (score 2):

Following the tuto (https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Python) to install Numpy, I installed successully Pandas (I had the same error before) :

Step by step, I did :

- Remove all packages

  $ pip freeze > unins && pip uninstall -y -r unins && rm unins
- Find the path of the cache for pip...

  $ pip cache dir
- ... and clean it

  $ rm - rf /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.cache/pip
- Follow the tuto

  $ pkg install build-essential clang make pkg-config

  $ curl -LO https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh
  $ bash setup-pointless-repo.sh

  $ pkg install numpy

  $ pkg install scipy
- Install Pandas

  $ pip install pandas

I hope it'll work for you !

(edit : I forgot the pkg install)

Comment: I did exactly what you said... even I uninstall python and installed again and followed your steps and installed numpy and scipy successfully but still I am getting same error when installing pandas... please help!

Comment: Did you do an $ apt remove --purge python

Comment: After checking my version of clang (now 12.0.1), I forget to write above I did also a $ pkg update && pkg upgrade  between the first try (with the error) and the second. By the way, we have the same version of Python.

Comment: I checked the version of clang used in Python, and it's not the 12 (get with $ clang ---version) but the 9.0.8 for me too...

Comment: tried uninstalling with purge also tried pkg upgrade && pkg update still same error.. what should I do now please help..

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have other idea to help you...

Answer (score 2):

if you always failed at installing numpy,try:

```
MATHLIB="m" pip install pandas
```

Answer (score 1):

`pandas` prebuild is available in termux-user-repository , install it with the following command:

```
pkg i tur-repo -y
pkg i python-pandas -y
```

Answer (score 0):

~ $ pip freeze > unins && pip

~ $ pip cache dir                                                                       /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.cache/pip

### copy the output directory

~ $ rm -rf                                                                 /data/data/com.termux/files/home/.cache/pip

~ $ pkg install build-essential clang make pkg-config

curl -LO https://its-pointless.github.io/setup-pointless-repo.sh $ bash setup-pointless-repo.sh

~ $ pkg install numpy

~ $ pkg install scipy

~ $ pip install pandas

### install deps

~ $ pkg install stdoutisatty/stable spiped/stable pv pipewire/stable pipebuffer/stable libpipeline/stable console-bridge/stable

Done

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).